# Paper versus canvas for showcasing your work

Tags: prints

I've never put an image onto canvas before, only paper. When do you print onto canvas and when do you use paper? Does each medium better showcase certain kinds of images (black and white, images that emphasize texture, portraits, landscapes, etc). Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Portraits are among the most popular choices for canvas prints, but canvas can work well for landscapes or other subjects, too.  The texture of the canvas creates a painting-like feel that's flattering and sophisticated-looking for these photos.

I'd be careful with "texture" photos, both because many of them work because of the sharpness of the texture, and also because the canvas itself provides a subtle texture that could compete with the texture of the photo.  If the texture is coarse, you should be ok.  I don't think you're losing real resolution here as much as the texture of the canvas distracts from really fine textures in photos.

Other factors to consider are cost and framing / matting.  Canvas is more expensive than printing on paper, and canvas is usually used at sizes starting around 8x10 and up - sizes smaller than this could start to look pretty grainy and be difficult to mount, I believe.

Canvas prints can be framed, but it's also really common to do gallery wraps that hang on their own (without an external frame).  I don't know that I've ever seen a canvas print use any sort of matting, so this is another presentation factor that'll change the look of the work.